# Integrating NuGet to existing project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

We have a very project, and we decided to build it's core as a set of NuGet dependencies using TeamCity. And now we want to import those NuGet packages to the rest of project.

Core can be updated several times a day, and project must use only the latest version. But when we removed version specification or set it as `version=""`, it still used the old version.

So, we want our project to use the latest libraries on *each* build. Can you post some recomendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on just TeamCity you could take a look at the [NuGet update options that TeamCity provides](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/NuGet+Installer). They have build options such as **Update packages with help of NuGet update command** which you could try.

If you want something similar when you build on a developer's machine then you will need to look at some pre-build step that uses NuGet update.